# Elastic search With MongoDB : Searching PDFs

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I were trying to save my pdf file in Mongo Db's gridFS and then searching in that pdfs using elastic search. I performed following :

1) Mongo DB Side:

```
mongod --port 27017 --replSet rs0 --dbpath "D:\Mongo-DB\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.7\data17"
mongod --port 27018 --replSet rs0 --dbpath "D:\Mongo-DB\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.7\data18"
mongod --port 27019 --replSet rs0 --dbpath "D:\Mongo-DB\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.7\data19"

mongo localhost:27017
rs.initiate()
rs.add("hostname:27018")
rs.add("hostname:27019")

mongofiles -hlocalhost:27017 --db testmongo --collection files --type application/pdf put D:\Sherlock-Holmes.pdf
```

2) Elastic Search Side (Installed Plugins : bigdesk/head/mapper-attachments/river-mongodb)

-> Using Elastic Search Head given following request from "Any request" tab

```
URL : http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/
_meta/PUT

{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "db": "testmongo",
    "collection": "fs.files",
    "gridfs": true,
    "contentType": "",
    "content": "base64 /path/filename | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g'"
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "testmongo",
    "type": "files",
    "content_type": "application/pdf"
  }
}
```

Now i am trying to access following URL :

```
http://localhost:9200/testmongo/files/508e82e21e43def09b5e1602?pretty=true
```

I got following response (Which i believe is as expected) :

```
{
  "_index" : "testmongo",
  "_type" : "files",
  "_id" : "508e82e21e43def09b5e1602",
  "_version" : 1,
  "exists" : true, "_source" : {"_id":"508e82e21e43def09b5e1602","filename":"D:\\Sherlock-Holmes.pdf","chunkSize":262144,"uploadDate":"2012-10-29T13:21:38.969Z","md5":"025fa2046f9254d2aecb9e52ae851065","length":98272,"contentType":"application/pdf"}
}
```

But when i were trying to search on this pdf using following URL:

```
http://localhost:9200/testmongo/files/_search?q=Albers&pretty=true
```

Its giving me following result :

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Here its showing me no any hit but word "Albers" present in this pdf. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to specify the property to be searched

```
http://localhost:9200/testmongo/files/_search?q=<PROPERTYNAME>:Albers&pretty=true
```

or even for complex searches

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200testmongo/files/_search?q' -d '{
    <PROPERTYNAME> : "value",
    <PROPERTYNAME> : {
                          <PROPERTYNAME> : "value",
                          <PROPERTYNAME> : "value"
                     }
}
'
```

but as far as i know you can only search for your defined properties after indexing your data.

Comment: I read documentation that we can use ES for search different attachment type text [like pdf/doc etc] since ES internally use apache TIKA for fetching texts from different files. In your solution how will we create properties from actual texts of different files?

Comment: I only worked a little on elastic search, but as I understood elastic search attachments it only indexes the meta data of your attachments. so these meta data should be available for searching like `date`, `title`, `author`, `keywords`. These data should be accessible as kind of properties like `my_attachment.author` for example