# Elastic Search using MongoDB in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, elasticsearch

I have to create text search using Elastic Search on MongoDB. It could be full text search and also hint based search, i.e "Did you Mean:" feature like google.

The main problem for me is, I am new to elastic and unable to find any sample in c# .net .

Please help.

Comment: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/I-am-tired-of-continuously-trying-to-override-the-default-analyzer-and-tokanizer-settings-td3350150.html#a3354293 here I had a hint, that if James Cook sais "I even replaced MongoDB with elasticsearch because I found its sharding and clustering capability (at the time) easier to use and its disk usage more efficient.", than MongoDB and Elastic Search are 2 different things, and cannot be used together

Comment: Tho http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122800/elastic-search-with-mongodb-searching-pdfs?rq=1 suggests otherwise...